# Circling label in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

To label a node with "1" in TikZ, I can use

```
\path (0,1) coordinate (P1) node[right=0.05cm] {1};
```

Is there a way to circle the label "1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `circle` and `draw` options to the node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\path (0,1) coordinate (P1) node[right=0.05cm,circle,draw] {1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the distance between the border and the `1` using, for example `inner sep=<length>`, or `minimum size=<length>`.

[image]